# Accepted answers are not display with green coloured circle

Tags: bug, design, accepted-answer

When seeing the questions from the [main page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) the accepted questions has the green coloured circle. Like the below:

[image: Answered and Accepted - Green coloured circled]

But in the [Questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions) page, the accepted questions are doesn't have the green coloured circle on it.

When inspect the element for the answers block, the css class `answered-accepted` is applied for the accepted post, but it is not reflect in the page.

Screenshot for reference:

The question doesn't have the accepted answer, the css class is `answered`

> [image: Answered post]

The question has the accepted answer, the css class is `answered-accepted`

> [image: Answered and accepted post]

Comment: The green background and white text at TSE is actually set on the `div.mini-counts`, which is a child element of `div.answered-accepted` on some screens but not on the Questions views, and this seems to be true across SE. Workplace sets the background on `div.answered-accepted` whereas English Language Learners sets the background on the [strong] child element.